# Redirect or deny direct access to public folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I using this htaccess to access `public/css`, `public/js`, `public/images` folders directly, it rewrite remove public from url:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Eg. when access this url `http://localhost/css/file.css` shows `http://localhost/public/css/file.css`

I want deny access to url `http://localhost/public/css/file.css` but allow `http://localhost/css/file.css`, it is possible to do this?

Comment: Can I ask why does it matter? Either way, you can still access the css file. Which is in the source anyway. All the assets are going to be available to the client.

Comment: @PanamaJack Thank you for your attention, there is no special reason, it would be a matter of "canonical URL".

Comment: The problem I was thinking was because, the user never see's the URL's and you can use a robots.txt to prevent crawling that folder but I just didn't see the point on an assets folder that has to be available for the page to show correctly.

Comment: Good job at solving it on your own and good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solve the problem you can use `%{THE_REQUEST}` with `RewriteCond`, example:

```
RewriteCond "%{THE_REQUEST}" "^GET\s/public/"
```

If needs any methods (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, etc), redirect eg.:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond "%{THE_REQUEST}" "^[A-Z]+\s/public/"
    RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ other-directory/$0 [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Deny access eg.:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond "%{THE_REQUEST}" "^[A-Z]+\s/public/"
    RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ fake-directory/$0 [F]

    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```